# How to center the data after enclosing a router-outlet in a div?

Tags: css, angular

This is how my page looks when I use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the app component.html

[image]

But when I change it to

```
<div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My page becomes this [image]

The css i am using to center the white box is

```
.centered-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

So how i do make it like before?

Comment: There is no div with the class `centered-content` in the code you posted.

Comment: @cloned the class centered-content is in my component's scss file. That's why its centered initially. even if i add it to the div it makes no difference

Comment: @adityasingh it would make it easier to see your full html structure and the styles you have applied to your components. A wild guess is that some styles you expect to be applied on the component resolved by the router, are actually applied to the div wrapping the outlet, in which case `<div style="display: contents">` would resolve it.